# Seeding data with faker gem not working with all db associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, faker

I'm trying to seed data using the faker gem and I'm getting a very weird result. The categories populate using the gem however articles do not populate. I've tested inputting data in the db with associations and it works fine. I'm not getting any error messages when I run

> rake db:seed

Here is the seeds.rb file.

```
# Create 8 seed categories
categories = Category.create([
        { name: 'History'}, {name: 'Biology'}, {name: 'Literature'},
        { name: 'Mathematics'}, { name: 'Music Theory'}, { name: 'Computer Science'},
        { name: 'Sociology'}, {name: 'Chemistry'}
    ])

# create 50 articles, with random titles, 250 words of content, and
# randomly assign one of the categories above to each article
for i in 0..49
    title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(rand(2..10)).chomp('.')
    content = Faker::Lorem.paragraph(word_count=250)

    # randomly assign one of the categories we just created 
    category = Category.first(offset: rand(Category.count)) 
    a = Article.create(title: title, content: content, categories: [category,])
end
```

Again it works to create categories but it does not create Articles. Below are all the models used for the db.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :article_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :content, presence: true
    validates :categories, presence: true
end


class ArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :category
    validates :article_id, presence: true
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :article_categories
    has_many :articles, through: :article_categories
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: remove `,` from `categories: ...,]` and replace `create` with `create!` that should raise an error if it fails.

Comment: Ok, that worked to force the error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Article categories is invalid`....Any clues?

Comment: I'm not sure. try `a = Article.new(title: title, content: content); a.categories << category; a.save!` (or a.categories.build).